# Single output on timer c#

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner and trying to understand what timer is and how can I use it. I'll be really grateful to you if you replied to my question.

I have a timer called "Elapsed_Time" and I set the interval to 1000 millisecond.
What I wanted to achieve is to show my message: "Hi just once" just once instead of showing it for every 1 second.

```
       private void Elapsed_Time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         Messagebox.show("Hi just once");
       }
```

Comment: You need to disable the timer inside your event handler - that will keep it from ticking again.  Depending on the timer you're using, you're looking for either a Stop method or a way to change the interval to infinity.

Comment: For what a Timer is and what it's used for you should start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I wanted to timer to keep on ticking and I just wanted to show the message only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you still want the timer's Tick event to fire then try this...

```
private bool _hasTicked = false;

private void Elapsed_Time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!_hasTicked)
     {
         Messagebox.show("Hi just once");
         _hasTicked = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: I'll wait 10 minutes to make it as answered. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Elapsed_Time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    Messagebox.show("Hi just once");
    Elapsed_Time_Tick.Enabled = false;      
}
```

You can do like this